# PayPal return URL variables from select options

Tags: php, forms, post, paypal

I am creating a paypal button on my site and would like to get/post a variable to the success url. Here is my code so far:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="GFFJUC8YBXTSHQ3">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Credits">Credits</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <select name="os0">
            <option value="5 Credits">5 Credits £5.00 GBP</option>
            <option value="10 Credits">10 Credits £10.00 GBP</option>
            <option value="20 Credits">20 Credits £20.00 GBP</option>
            <option value="50 Credits">50 Credits £50.00 GBP</option>
            <option value="TEST">TEST £0.01 GBP</option>
        </select> 
    </td></tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">   

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['os0']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['os0']; ?>" />  

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/?order_status=success&value=<?php echo $_REQUEST['os0']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="image" src="http://example.com/buynow.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But for some reason the value variable returns empty, and get a lot of other variables. here is the success url returned:

```
?order_status=success&value=&tx=92680583NA758023W&st=Completed&amt=0%2e01&cc=GBP&cm=&item_number=
```

Any ideas what is going on, and why the value variable is null?

Comment: Can you print the value of the `$_REQUEST['os0'];` ? If it is empty the value will not be printed in the URL.

Comment: Try to hardcode the value `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/?order_status=success&value=TEST">` and then check weather TEST will be set in the returning URL

Answer (score 0):

'return' function is actually the URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your site that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page. PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage by default.

If you want to would like to get/post a variable to the success url, you can use PayPal IPN function to get/post transaction details to your URL. Please refer to the link below for the details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/